# How to block javascript alert box in Gecko C#

Tags: javascript, c#, gecko, geckofx

I am trying to block JavaScript Alert Box in Gecko Browser Engine.

I have tried this code but doesn't work at all..

```
 internal class FilteredPromptService : nsIPromptService2, nsIPrompt
    {
        private static PromptService _promptService = new PromptService();

        public void Alert(nsIDOMWindow aParent, string aDialogTitle, string aText)
        {

        // do nothing 
        }
    }
```

Having difficulties while trying to disable JavaScript alert box.

Comment: Why would you even want to do that?

Comment: There are some website that I'm visiting that contains some advertisement. that's shows alert box.

Comment: So, install a popup blocker. Blocking all alerts seems counter-productive.

Comment: installing a popup blocker in gecko using c#?

Comment: In the browser, I mean.

Comment: I know about that but, I want to do this with coding.